# Effeciently extract last 12 month data from master table for each id and month using sas

Tags: sas

I am currently practicing SAS programming on using two SAS dataset(sample and master) . Below are the hypothetical or dummy data created for illustration purpose to solve my problem through SAS programming . I would like to extract the data for the id's in sample dataset from master dataset. I have given an example with few id's as sample dataset,  for which i need to extract last 12 month information from master table for each id's based on the yearmonth information( desired output given in the third output).

similar to this, i have many column which i need 12 months data for each id and yearmonth.

I have written a code with do loop to iterate each row of sample dataset then find the data in the master table from start (yearmonth and end date(12 month ago) for each iteration, and then transpose it using proc transpose. Then merge the sample dataset with transpose data using data step merge using id and yearmonth. But i feel the code which i have written is not optimized because it is lopping several times for each row in sample dataset and finds data from master table . Can anyone help me in solving this problem using SAS programming with optimized way.

1. One sample dataset (dataset name - sample).

```html
ID  YEARMONTH NO_OF_CUST
1    200909     50
1    201005     65
1    201008     78
1    201106     95
2    200901     65
2    200902     45
2    200903     69
2    201005     14
2    201006     26
2    201007     98
3    201011     75
3    201012     75
```

---

2. One master dataset(dataset name - master dataset huge dataset over the year for each id from start of the account to till date.)

```html
ID YEARMONTH NO_OF_CUST

1 200808 125
1 200809 125
1 200810 111
1 200811 174
1 200812 98
1 200901 45
1 200902 74
1 200903 73
1 200904 101
1 200905 164
1 200906 104
1 200907 22
1 200908 35
1 200909 50
1 200910 77
1 200911 86
1 200912 95
1 201001 95
1 201002 87
1 201003 79
1 201004 71
1 201005 65
1 201006 66
1 201007 66
1 201008 78
1 201009 88
1 201010 54
1 201011 45
1 201012 100
1 201101 136
1 201102 111
1 201103 17
1 201104 77
1 201105 111
1 201106 95
1 201107 79
1 201108 777
1 201109 758
1 201110 32
1 201111 15
1 201112 22
2 200711 150
2 200712 150
2 200801 44
2 200802 385
2 200803 65
2 200804 66
2 200805 200
2 200806 333
2 200807 285
2 200808 265
2 200809 222
2 200810 220
2 200811 205
2 200812 185
2 200901 65
2 200902 45
2 200903 69
2 200904 546
2 200905 21
2 200906 256
2 200907 214
2 200908 14
2 200909 44
2 200910 65
2 200911 88
2 200912 79
2 201001 65
2 201002 45
2 201003 69
2 201004 54
2 201005 14
2 201006 26
2 201007 98
3 200912 77
3 201001 66
3 201002 69
3 201003 7
3 201004 7
3 201005 7
3 201006 65
3 201007 75
3 201008 85
3 201009 89
3 201010 100
3 201011 75
3 201012 75
```

Below is sample output which i am trying to update for an each sample id's in sample dataset.

[image]

Comment: If you replace these images with text tables, we can copy & paste your field names into our answers. Examples: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-to-create-table-in-so-question

Comment: Also because your question is about broadly about writing optimized code,  instead of a specific programming question, you might want to try asking here instead: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1. You've included data as an image. For us to use this data we would have to type it out. 2. You haven't posted the code you do have so far indicating any attempt at solving the problem. 3. This isn't just about reformatting data you need to state the logic for the calculations you need. 4. This is not a valid SO question because its more like a full assignment and your job. You can ask specific questions but this is way too broad.

Comment: While it's not really clear what you want it sounds like you will need to index the data set.  Look into that and see if that answers your question

Comment: Edited the question and pasted number instead of image. Also I have given the coding method which I adopted.

Comment: Anyone assist with this issues.

Answer (score 1):

Without sample code of what you've been trying to do so far it is a bit difficult to figure out what you want but a "SAS" way of getting the same result as the image file might be the following.

EDIT: Edited my answer so it takes the last 12 months by ID

```
data test;
    infile datalines dlm='09'x;
    input ID YEARMONTH NO_OF_CUST;
    datalines;
1   200808  125
1   200809  125
1   200810  111
1   200811  174
1   200812  98
1   200901  45
1   200902  74
1   200903  73
1   200904  101
1   200905  164
1   200906  104
1   200907  22
1   200908  35
1   200909  50
1   200910  77
1   200911  86
1   200912  95
1   201001  95
1   201002  87
1   201003  79
1   201004  71
1   201005  65
1   201006  66
1   201007  66
1   201008  78
1   201009  88
1   201010  54
1   201011  45
1   201012  100
1   201101  136
1   201102  111
1   201103  17
1   201104  77
1   201105  111
1   201106  95
1   201107  79
1   201108  777
1   201109  758
1   201110  32
1   201111  15
1   201112  22
2   200711  150
2   200712  150
2   200801  44
2   200802  385
2   200803  65
2   200804  66
2   200805  200
2   200806  333
2   200807  285
2   200808  265
2   200809  222
2   200810  220
2   200811  205
2   200812  185
2   200901  65
2   200902  45
2   200903  69
2   200904  546
2   200905  21
2   200906  256
2   200907  214
2   200908  14
2   200909  44
2   200910  65
2   200911  88
2   200912  79
2   201001  65
2   201002  45
2   201003  69
2   201004  54
2   201005  14
2   201006  26
2   201007  98
3   200912  77
3   201001  66
3   201002  69
3   201003  7
3   201004  7
3   201005  7
3   201006  65
3   201007  75
3   201008  85
3   201009  89
3   201010  100
3   201011  75
3   201012  75
;
run;

proc sort data=test;
    by id yearmonth;
run;

data result;
    set test;
    array prev_month {13} PREV_MONTH_0-PREV_MONTH_12;
    by id;

    if first.id then do;
        do i = 1 to 13;
            prev_month(i) = 0;
        end;
    end;

    do i = 13 to 2 by -1;
        prev_month(i) = prev_month(i-1);
    end;
    prev_month(1) = NO_OF_CUST;

    drop i PREV_MONTH_0;
    retain PREV_MONTH:;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine to extract previous 12 month data. What is to be changed in case If I want to extract next 12 month data

Comment: How to get next 12 month records as pulled previous 12 month

Comment: Try adding decending before the yearmonth variable in sort